# Display Vertical column lists in large screen and stacked drop down in mobile screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

In need of an effective solution to display vertical column list in desktop/large screen and the same has to be displayed as a stacked dropdown list on mobile screens. (html/css/bootstrap)

Please refer the image.

**Desktop/Large screen:**

[image]

**Mobile Screen :**

[image]

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flexbox` in combination with `media-queries`,

Apply `display: flex;` to the list container. And apply `flex-direction: column;` to list container inside your required media-queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries like this:

@media (max-width:1000px){*Class name*{*properties*}}